# Define upper and lower polygonal limits of a polygon set

Tags: python, geometry, polygon, polygons

[image: polygons (blue) and common centroid (red)]

I have a list `P` containing 4-sided polygons defined by four 2D points `A,B,C,D`. Each polygon has the same centroid as the others.

I want to find:

- (1) the **largest** polygon `p1 = ((x1,y1),(x2,y2),(x3,y3),(x4,y4))` that can **fit** in all polygons of the list `P`
- (2) the **smallest** polygon `p2 = ((x5,y5),(x6,y6),(x7,y7),(x8,y8))` that can **contain** all polygons of the list `P`

Comment: Is the orientation of the polygon going to be static (ie defined by the points) or can the polygon be rotated (ie the points define the relative angles and lengths of the sides)?

Comment: the polygons can be rotated

Comment: @shawn-s axial symmetry can also be applied if necessary, as rotation can be